# Erro ao instalar o package Scrapy em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando instalar Scrapy através do pip, mas venho obtendo erros do tipo:

> running build_ext
>
> buildig 'lxml.etree' extension
>
> erro: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find
>   vcvarsall.bat).

Já possuo o VSC++ 10 instalado. Estou utilizando a versão Python 3.4.4 e o Windows 7. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Muitos pacotes Python são chatos para instalar com PIP em Windows pois precisam de outras ferramentas para compilar.

Eu tentaria instalar já precompilado.

1. Ache o link para o pacote desejado aqui http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scrapy . Normalmente você precisaria escolher a versão certa, Python 3 vs Python 2, 32-bit vs 64-bit. Mas nesse caso parece que só há uma versão.
2. Baixe o arquivo wheel (.whl) do link
3. Instale com PIP: `pip install c:\caminho\para\Scrapy‑1.2.1‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`

É assim que eu instalo NumPy e matplotlib dentre outros em Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais conveniente de instalar o [scrap](/questions/tagged/scrap) no [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) e muito outras coisas no windows é utilizando a *linha de comando* [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) e gestor de pacotes `conda` do [anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda):

1. Ctrl+r
2. cmd
3. `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`

Se ainda não tem o `conda` instado: [YouTube: como instalar instalar o anaconda no Windows](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=como+instalar+instalar+o+anaconda+no+Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Veja este [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/):

> However, if you are targeting Python 3.3 and 3.4 (and did not have
>   access to Visual Studio 2010), building is slightly more complicated.
>   You will need to open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (selecting the
>   x64 version if using 64-bit Python) and run set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
>   before calling pip install.

Parece que você precisa abrir um shell no Visual Studio e chamar o pip install de lá de dentro.